# How to set a breakpoint just before exit in golang

Tags: debugging, go, gdb, breakpoints, exit

I am a complete beginner in golang, in fact I am debugging someone else's program to find out the cause of an unexpected exit.

I want to know how can I set a breakpoint in `gdb` at the "exit" routine called just before the program shuts down?

I have so far tried

```
gdb <program name>
run
<...wait for program to quit>
break 'runtime.goexit'
run
<...wait for program to break>
```

But it does not break, instead it just exits.

Comment: Does it merely exit or panics (i.e. crashes loudly with a stack trace dumped)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to source code you can add a `defer` to handle exit from arbitrary point like:

https://play.golang.org/p/uliAc3j7f-

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("Place breakpoint here")    
        if recovered := recover(); recovered != nil {
            fmt.Println("Handled panic:", recovered)    
        }
    }()
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    panic("Something went wrong")
}
```

Also Go is case sensitive so try `break 'runtime.Goexit'` - see https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Goexit

Comment: Is there some reason why I would not set the breakpoint in gdb? I read somewhere that golang+gdb could be unstable. But I was hoping it was just that I didn't know how to use it properly.

Comment: Sorry, I never used `gdb` so can't answer your question. But maybe your issue with invalid case - the `Goexit` is starting from upper case- https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Goexit. Try `break 'runtime.Goexit'`?

Answer (score 0):

> But it does not break, instead it just exits.

You can use `catch syscall exit` (or `catch sycall exit_group` if you are 
 on Linux).

That is guaranteed to stop the program if it really exists (as opposed to being terminated by a signal).